# Running Chimp with Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-cucumber

Installed Chimp globally and locally for my app. Created `features` directory at the root of my app. Put in a feature file `insertContract.feature` with the following scenario.

```
Feature: Input contact information

As a contract admin
I want to input contact information
So that I can save it in a database

@watch
Scenario: Go to the contract insert page
    Given I have visited Contract Insert page
    Then I see an input "supplierName"
```

Ran chimp.

```
chimp --ddp=http://localhost:7001 --watch
```

Chimp says it is running and watching tages @watch, @focus, @dev. But it does not pick up anything from the feature file.

```
Sudis-MacBook-Pro:contract tupun$ chimp --ddp=http://localhost:7001 --watch 
[chimp] Watching features with tagged with @dev,@watch,@focus

[chimp] Running...
```

It is supposed to provide me with the stubs for step-definition. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that you do everything right and it should work. Probably some mistype somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I just started to use chimp too, and i use @focus instead @watch for get the definitions

[image]

I hope, this helpt you.

cheers.